# How to get a shapefile from Google Maps

Tags: google-maps

I have a use case where I want to generate random points within a geometry. For more use cause, the geometry is a district with my country. For example, [West Bay, Grand Cayman](https://www.google.com/maps/@19.3617772,-81.4005774,13.03z?entry=ttu).

If I search for the district in Google Maps, it brings it up with the district outlined. How do I download the points that makeup that geometry so I can use Python to generate random points within that geometry?

Or is there an easier way to get random points within a specified geometry? Remembering that I want to make sure it is definitely within the district boundaries and not in the middle of a pond or harbour.

Comment: You can't.  You'll need to find the data elsewhere

Comment: Maybe consider OpenStreetMap for your data needs:  https://www.openstreetmap.org/export#map=13/19.3549/-81.3723

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else who runs into this, I was able to get what I want from OpenStreetBrowser.com.

https://www.openstreetbrowser.org/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is not a valid criticism from the StackExchange Bot. Yes, the answer is short. But that's because once the hyperlink is accessed, the answer is obvious.